# Why is my custom field being returned as null in a before update trigger on Opportunity when the field is populated?

Tags: apex

I have a before update trigger on Opportunity that uses this query to get values ->

```
List<Opportunity> opportunities = [SELECT Id, StageName, Probability, Project_Manager__c, Opportunity_Line_of_Business__c, RecordType.Name,(SELECT Id FROM OpportunityContactRoles) FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN : Trigger.newMap.keySet()];
```

The value for Project_Manager__c is returned correctly if the trigger fires from doing an edit on the Opportunity, but when a new product is added to the Opportunity and the trigger fires the Project_Manager__c field is null. All other fields in the query seem to be returned correctly but the Project_Manager__c field. The Project_Manager__c is just a custom field on the Opportunity just like the Opportunity_Line_of_Business__c field is so why would it not be returned in the trigger when a new product is added to the Opportunity?

Comment: It shouldn't be. I suspect that your question is related to a NPE (Null Pointer Exception) that happened downstream, and you've incorrectly identified the problem as the field. It could be a missing entry in a map, a number you're trying to do math on, etc. Could you please post *the exact line* where you are getting the exception?

Comment: An exception is not returned. In the trigger we are checking to make sure the custom project manager pick list field is populated if the probability of the opportunity is greater than 49 percent and a product description on the opportunity contains criteria. When a product is added to the opportunity and the trigger fires the Project_Manager__c field is always null even if the field is populated.

Comment: We still need more information. The database should be returning a value, especially in a query, even from a related object (e.g. the children records). We're going to need to see more code. The problem is almost certainly elsewhere.

Comment: Here the code for the trigger

Comment: List<Opportunity> opportunities = [SELECT Id, StageName, Probability, Project_Manager__c, Opportunity_Intergaph_Line_of_Business__c, RecordType.Name,(SELECT Id FROM OpportunityContactRoles) FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN : Trigger.newMap.keySet()];                String newStageName;
    String NewLnOfBus;
    String NewPrjMgr;
    Decimal newProbability;
    for (Opportunity opportunity : opportunities) 
        {
        NewPrjMgr = Trigger.newMap.get(opportunity.Id).Project_Manager__c
        if (newProbability >= 50 &&  NewPrjMgr == null

Comment: So I presume that for some reason you're observing that your `if` statement is executing unexpectedly?

Comment: The problem is the value return by the statement NewPrjMgr = Trigger.newMap.get(opportunity.Id).Project_Manager__c and tested in the if statement is null when it is really not null in the database. Therefore, the trigger cannot work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. There was an unfinished workflow rule on the Opportunity Product entered by a previous administrator that updated the Opportunity: Project_Manager__c field to nothing. The workflow rule was firing before the trigger when a product was added to the opportunity so it was setting it to null.